# Best Practice with C#. Is it okay to pass parameters with await?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it okay to pass parameters, with `await`? what are the PROS and CONS of doing this?

```
var results = MapResults(await GetDataAsync());
```

Comment: That is fine.All you are doing is resolving the Task before passing the parameter. It is exactly the same as var x = await GetDataAsync; var results = MapResults(x); Makes not difference, and it usually comes down to the coding guidelines you want to implement for yourself

Comment: Code readability.  That's literally the same thing as `var result = await GetDataAsync(); var map = MapResults(result)`

Comment: @Zer0 which one is readable, the one with var results ? or the single line?

Comment: @Heinrich yup, I agree with you. I just worry that I am applying some bad practice on my code for doing a single line.

Comment: One practical reason I personally prefer two lines is it makes for easier debugging when stepping line by line.  My worry, if I wrote it in one line, is that other coders won't truly understand what a single line of code is doing.  You have two methods running plus an `await`.   That said, this really comes down to preference.  It's like asking why you should or should not use camelCase.

Comment: @DrewAguirre honestly it is much for muchness. In the project I am working on atm it is quiet common to see that. Usually as long as your code fits on one line then it usually stays clear enough. From the opposite perspective, Zer0 makes just as much of a valid point about using two lines.

Comment: since we all here, thank you for answering my concern. ya'll.. 

another question is , what is the difference between the await GetDataAsync() and GetDataAsync().Result ?

Comment: @DrewAguirre: those last two are *completely different* and **YOU MUST NOT DO THE LATTER**.  I hope that was clear.  The former does an asynchronous wait; the latter does a synchronous wait on an asynchronous workflow. Now, suppose the asynchronous workflow has scheduled work *in the future on the current thread*. A synchronous wait means "sleep this thread until the work that this thread will do in the future is done", and obviously that sleeps forever.

Comment: By contrast, an asynchronous wait means "find more work to do on this thread and come back here when the awaited task is complete". That "more work to do" might include *in the future* doing work that completes the task.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

UPDATE: This question was [the subject of my blog in March 2020](https://ericlippert.com/2020/03/10/passing-awaited-tasks/). See it for more discussion of this issue. Thanks for the interesting question!

---

I'm going to assume here that you intended that to be a function call as the sole member of the argument list.

As others have noted, there is no difference between

```
x = M(await FAsync());
```

and

```
var f = await FAsync();
x = M(f);
```

And that is the same as

```
var ftask = FAsync();
x = M(await ftask)
```

So it doesn't matter which way you write it, correct?

Give that some thought.

---

In that *specific* scenario all three workflows are the same. But there is a potential difference here if we only slightly vary the scenario. Consider:

```
x = M(await FAsync(), await GAsync());
```

This is the same as

```
var f = await FAsync();
var g = await GAsync();
x = M(f, g);
```

and what do we know about this workflow?  **The GAsync task is not started until the FAsync task is finished!** But it looks like there is an opportunity for having two tasks going at the same time here, which might use the current thread more efficiently! Likely the workflow would be better written as:

```
var ftask = FAsync();
var gtask = GAsync();
x = M(await ftask, await gtask);
```

Now FAsync and GAsync tasks both start, and we do not call M until both finish.

My advice is to think carefully about where you put your awaits. Remember, **an await is intended to be a point in an asynchronous workflow where the workflow asynchronously pauses until a precondition of the continuation is met**. If you can delay awaiting a task until it is *actually* a precondition, you might be able to eke out a performance win.

Comment: Of course it is good to be aware of the underlying multithreading support of the tasks you're awaiting. You can't await simultaneously on two tasks that yield data from the database and uses the same `SqlConnection` or `DbContext` for instance.

Comment: Wow! I am impressed.. sorry been busy and haven't replied on your answer.. I marked this one as the answer.. explanation is very clear.. and yup, I learned a lot just by reading the few lines you wrote.. and I have read your blog also.. good job! and keep it up..

Answer (score 5):

There is no runtime difference between;

```cs
var results = MapResults(await GetDataAsync())
```

and

```cs
var tmp = await GetDataAsync();
var results = MapResults(tmp)
```

Comment: Yup there is no difference. what I am thinking, is there a technical issue for doing this? or is it cleaner to use "tmp" variable? 

i can't see any disadvantage for using the first line. even there is an exception it will throw to GetDataAsync().

Comment: Is it a bad practice to do the first line ?

Comment: I prefer second pattern, 1) more read able, 2) I can massage the code before i pass to results.

Comment: Please note that OP used variable (`GetDataAsync`) and not method call. Depending on where that `Task GetDataAsync = CallSomeAsync()` is initialized there could be significant differences as task will be running already by the time `MapResults(await GetDataAsync)` is called. See Eric's answer for more details.

Comment: Yeah, since there wasn't enough context, I assumed it was a typo....

Comment: I prefere second one as well. @DrewAguirre If you need to go to debug and want to check the value of tmp in first case. You need to step into `MapResults`. While simply put a breakpoint after `tmp` in second case.